# Jenkins CI is skipping packages on nuget.exe restore my.sln

Tags: jenkins, nuget

After kicking of the Jenkins (v2.8) build, the Workspace is cleared, Git sources are pulled and a "nuget.exe restore my.sln" (v3.4.4) is issued using the "Execute Windows Batch Command" build task. Checking Jenkins console output indicates restore action:

```
NuGet Config files used:
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installed:
3 package(s) to packages.config projects
```

So far all looks good, but upon investigation some packages were skipped as my package.config actually contains **5 packages**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
   <package id="Dapper" version="1.42" targetFramework="net452" />
   <package id="FluentMigrator" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net452" />
   <package id="FluentMigrator.Runner" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="FluentValidation" version="6.1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Both Dapper and FluentValidation packages were skipped. My first thought, I probably made a silly error in my package configuration, or I'm accidentally referencing the wrong package.config... However, executing the exact same nuget restore command on the build server reveals:

```
NuGet Config files used:
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
C:\Users\admin\.nuget\packages\
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installed:
5 package(s) to packages.config projects
```

I'm at a loss as to why the Jenkins build task is skipping, or only partially downloading the required packages. Anybody out there with a similar experience?

**UPDATE:**

Created a brand new test project and included one of the missing packages, modified the jenkins project to pull this project from git instead. Hit nuget restore mytest.sln and it just works. Still don't understand why other sln doesn't work, but at least determined that this behaviour must be related to the solution, or one of its projects. Not spending any more time on this. Will recreate projects instead.

Comment: Might be some user related difference. Keep in mind that in you case Jenkins is started under system user not admin therefore all builds on "master" are executed under system user. You can try either configuring the Jenkins Windows service to run under the admin user or try connecting localhost as a different JNLP slave (under admin, of course) and setting your job to run in it.

Comment: @izzekil, its definitely worth investigating, but I just don't understand how permissions could be interfering and allow some packages to be download and others not...

Answer (score 2):

Oh my, do I feel like a rookie. Some of the packages were unintentionally committed to git. So when pulling sources from git, it also created a package folder with two packages in there. Which caused nuget restore to skip those as they already existed. It would have been very helpful if the output of nuget restore was to indicate that is was skipping package download in some form. Could have saved me hours!

Comment: I am having the same problem. Nuget restore is not restoring xunit Nuget packages, but I can't wrap my head around why. None of the xunit packages are in the source control.